# How to open many file.R extention tabs at 1 time in R project

Tags: r

in my R project, I had like almost 30 R scripts and now I have non. the only way to get my.30.file.R back the select one by one? from File -> Open File? I tried to do multiple selections with , : ; and shift didnt work out. does anyone know a short cut?

Comment: perhaps you might consider taking this as an opportunity to re-assess whether there's a better way to go about doing what you're doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have all .R files in your working directory, you can do this:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = ".R")    # get all .R files
file.edit(files)                       # open all scripts in separate tabs
```